# Is there a way of searching cases by a custom field using the netsuite php toolkit?

Tags: php, netsuite, php-toolkit

I am trying to pull cases based on a custom field, however whenever I try this I get the following error:

> SearchCustomField is an abstract type and cannot be instantiated

I have already looked through a few previous posts on here and this code previously worked for someone else: 
[Search Customer by custom field in Netsuite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18203226/search-customer-by-custom-field-in-netsuite)

```
$NSservice = new NetSuiteService();
$NSservice->setSearchPreferences(false, 10);

$cs = new CustomerSearch();
$csb = new CustomerSearchBasic();

$domain = new SearchCustomField();
$domain->internalId = '620';
$domain->searchValue = '8260';
$domain->operator = 'is';

$scfl = new SearchCustomFieldList();
$scfl->customField = array($domain);
$csb->customFieldList = $scfl;
$cs->basic = $csb;

$request = new SearchRequest();
$request->searchRecord = $cs;

$searchResponse = $NSservice->search($request);
```

Comment: Have you tried downloading the sample PHP application provided by NetSuite?

Comment: I have however unfortunately the sample application doesn't search through cases using a custom field.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [latest schema](https://www.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2018_2/schema/search/supportcasesearchbasic.html?mode=package) searching SupportCases by a custom field is definitely supported.

Looking at your code, the `internalId` of your custom field looks incorrect. Normally, the `internalId` specified in your search is a string, not a number. It will start with the prefix `cust`.

FWIW the PHP Toolkit has a good bunch of bugs. You may want to consider using the [ruby library](https://github.com/NetSweet/netsuite) which supports this operation and is well supported by the open source community.

Comment: The internalId is definately correct as ive printed the response from another request to double check it.

I will have a look at the ruby libary

Comment: At some point the `internalId` and `scriptId` were swapped. Depending on which API version you are using the wrong ID could be in the replace. I would look for an ID with a prefix of `cust`.